# Is it permissible to say no more than these zikrs in Ruku and Sijda, or are they only supplementary zikrs that should come with other main ones?

Tags: salat, sujud, dhikr

The following are zikrs that have been narrated in different sources as ones Prophet Muhammad -p.b.u.h- would recite in his daily prayers. (Needless to say, the wording in different sources may slightly vary from the following.)

> اللهم لك ركعت وبك آمنت، لك أسلمت، وعليك توكلت، أنت ربي خشع سمعي وبصري ودمي ولحمي وعظمي وعصبي لله رب العالمين
>
> اللهم لك سجدت وبك آمنت ولك أسلمت، سجد وجهي للذي خلقه وصوره وشق سمعه وبصره تبارك الله أحسن الخالقين

The question is whether saying theses prayers in Ruku and Sijda would suffice, or they need to be followed or preceded by other more common zikrs like the below ones (and similar ones)?

> سبحان ربّی العظیم
>
> سبحان ربّی الاعلی

Ajrukum IndAllah

UPDATE: What triggers the question to me is that the first two zikrs apparently contain no tangible sign of praise (tasbeeh) of Allah.

Comment: Well done, it could be indeed a helpful question (and answers) for many users as "FAQ" and deserve +vote. By the way, I tried to edit it slightly, although it was perfect enough.../ Good luck mate.

Answer (score 1):

I indeed appreciate your question a lot. Since commonly it is inquired a lot and looks interesting as well. It is declared that it is sufficient to recite every Zikr during the Ruku’ or Sujud (Sajdahs), and for the sake of precaution: it would be nicer if we recite a Zikr which be (at least) as much as the length of the following zikr:

> سبحان ربی العظیم (اعلی) و بحمده  / Or thrice سبحان الله
>
> توضیح المسائل مراجع، ج 1، ص 562

It is quoted that Imam Jafar al-Sadiq (pbuh) narrated from his father (Imam Muhammad Al-Baqer), and he has narrated from Imam Ali (pbuh) that said:

> There is no Qera’a (reciting) in the Ruku’ or Sujud. It is just
>   praising of Allah and then requesting and dua. Thus, start with Madh
>   and Thana (praise and eulogy) before dua, afterwards do dua.
>
> عبدالله بن جعفر حمیری قمی، قرب الاسناد، ص 66؛ وسائل‏الشیعة، ج 6، ص
>   309- 8046، عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ جَعْفَرٍ فِی قُرْبِ الْإِسْنَادِ عَنِ
>   السِّنْدِیِّ بْنِ مُحَمَّدٍ عَنْ أَبِی الْبَخْتَرِیِّ عَنْ جَعْفَرٍ
>   عَنْ أَبِیهِ أَنَّ عَلِیّاً ع کَانَ یَقُولُ لَا قِرَاءَةَ فِی رُکُوعٍ
>   وَ لَا سُجُودٍ إِنَّمَا فِیهِمَا الْمِدْحَةُ لِلَّهِ عَزَّ وَ جَلَّ
>   ثُمَّ الْمَسْأَلَةُ فَابْتَدِءُوا قَبْلَ الْمَسْأَلَةِ بِالْمِدْحَةِ
>   لِلَّهِ عَزَّ وَ جَلَّ ثُمَّ اسْأَلُوا بَعْدَهُ.

---

**Conclusion:**

Based on the mentioned issues and likewise other available information, the mentioned Zikr as you indicated, is considered as a Zikr(s) which could be better to recite them (and at least) it that length, not as obligation.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa2497)